# Where does the Heaven's Lost Property anime split from the manga?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

I finished the anime and now I want to read the manga, but what chapter should I start from so that I don't have to reread the same content again?

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, we prefer not to delete good questions that have good answers (like this one), but we can dissociate you from the question so that it isn't linked to your account. Would you like us to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read from the chapter where Ikaros and Delta fought Chaos. It differs starting from there. Update the chapter number later.

EDIT: Chapter 31. In the anime, Ikaros was thrown out from the water by her weaponry system. In the manga, she was saved by Astrea.